# Why does my website Certificate have a different 'Issued by' on different computers?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, windows-home-server

I have a small home server still running WHSv1 (and yes, I know Windows Server 2003 is no longer supported). Website is resisted through 'Windows Live Custom Domains'.

When I go to the website from my house, I see the certificate is being issued by 'Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2'. [Certificate 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mry2Z.jpg)
But when I view the site from my work, it see its issued by 'Websense Certificate Authority'.[Certificate 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Ddp.jpg)

Why does the Issuer appear to be different based on what computer I'm looking at the website from?

Comment: Differences in browser is what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your employer is using ssl proxy termination (also known as man-in-the-middle) to decrypt the web traffic and inspecting it before it leaves the network.

This is widely used by larger companies to control Web site usage based on the content (content filtering)

Comment: Thanks. I knew was behind a proxy at work... But not the extent of what it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the certification information.  Your work is issuing you their own certificate to your website.  This means they can intercept, record, and view all traffic between the PC at work and your website.

This is supported by my [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=websense&filters=ufn%3A%22websense%22%20sid%3A%2278904780-7715-1daf-f313-b439ada30702%22&form=EDGNTC&qs=MB&cvid=d6c6c9c6f7304412bd246f05df6ebd4e&pq=websense) search on Websense:

> Forcepoint, previously known as Websense and Raytheon|Websense

Which matches your certificate:

[image]